# Retain file pointer after function call, using the decorator pattern

Tags: python, methods, decorator

I need a decorator (or any other neat design pattern) for functions which are dealing with files. The main purpose is to remain the file pointer at the same position where it was, after the function acts on the file.

Here is my code, including some dummy tests. The problem is that the decorator doesn't work on instance methods, even if I pass the `args` and `kwargs` to it. I could not figure out how to design the code…

```
import unittest
from cStringIO import StringIO


def remain_file_pointer(file_obj):
    def wrap(f):
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            old_position = file_obj.tell()
            f(*args, **kwargs)
            file_obj.seek(old_position, 0)
        return wrapped_f
    return wrap


class TestRemainFilepointer(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_remains_filepointer(self):
        dummy_file = StringIO('abcdefg')

        @remain_file_pointer(dummy_file)
        def seek_into_file(dummy_file):
            dummy_file.seek(1, 0)

        self.assertEqual(0, dummy_file.tell())
        seek_into_file(dummy_file)
        self.assertEqual(0, dummy_file.tell())

    def test_remains_filepointer_in_class_method(self):

        class FileSeekerClass(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.dummy_file = StringIO('abcdefg')

            @remain_file_pointer(self.dummy_file)
            def seek_into_file(self):
                self.dummy_file.seek(1, 0)

        fileseeker = FileSeekerClass()
        self.assertEqual(0, fileseeker.dummy_file.tell())
        fileseeker.seek_into_file()
        self.assertEqual(0, fileseeker.dummy_file.tell())
```

**UPDATE:**
Just to clarify the basic idea:

The decorator should take an argument, which is a file handler and store the position before the actual function manipulates the file. After that, the pointer should be set to the old position. And this should work either for standalone functions and for methods.

My answer below fixes the problem by assuming that the last argument in the function is the file handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not mark this as the final answer, since I'm pretty sure  there is a better design.

I came up with a solution which assumes that the last argument of the data-manipulating function is the file handler and access it via `args[-1]`:

```
def remain_file_pointer(f):
    """Remain the file pointer position after calling the decorated function

    This decorator assumes that the last argument is the file handler.

    """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        file_obj = args[-1]
        old_position = file_obj.tell()
        return_value = f(*args, **kwargs)
        file_obj.seek(old_position, 0)
        return return_value
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Don't forget about the wrapped function's return value.

Comment: @RSamuelKlatchko ah many thanks! I just added more unit tests for this.